# Correctly defined Javascript function sometimes causing TypeError: "X" is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a React (^16.12.0) application. I use Chrome but the same error occurs using Firefox and on other machines.

Here's the link to the application: [resume-designer.com](https://resume-designer.com/). After several clicks on the big blue *Add* button, you'll eventually see the below error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: r[t] is not a function
```

Here's the code in question:

```js
// src/defaults/content.js

export const education = () => ({
  city: '',
  country: '',
  degree: '',
  description: emptyDesc(),
  id: shortid.generate(),
  school: '',
});

export const experiences = () => ({
  city: '',
  country: '',
  description: emptyDesc(),
  employer: '',
  id: shortid.generate(),
  position: '',
});
```

```js
// src/actions/content.js

import * as defaults from '../defaults/content';

export const addItem = (event) => {
  const { section } = event.target.dataset;

  return {
    newItem: defaults[section](), // <-- This causes the problem (sometimes)
    path: section,
    type: 'ADD_ITEM',
  };
};
```

To see what was going on, I added `console.log(defaults[section]);` statement in `src/actions/content.js` on line 7, just before the `return` statement. Clicking four times (it's not always four) on the mentioned button eventually caused the expected error. On the below screenshot, we see that, for the first three clicks, the function is correctly defined and called, but for the fourth one, it's now undefined () and causes the error. Note that if you keep clicking, it starts working again, then crashes, then works, etc.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried moving the `education()` and `experiences()` functions from `src/defaults/content.js` to `src/actions/content.js` and I still get the same error.

Any idea? Could it be a memory deficiency problem?

- Link to the application: https://resume-designer.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are listening to click events on your button that has children. Children also trigger the listener by event-bubbeling. In your case you have the dataset information of `data-section` on the "outside element". But because sometimes children trigger the event, your `event.target` is not your expected "outside element" (try clicking on the text and your error always will appear)

Your problem is in the line `const { section } = event.target.dataset;`

You can add CSS to your outer element's children `pointer-events: none;` that clicks on your children are ignored. Alternative you can ensure to cancel the bubbling of the event on your children by calling `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Thank you buddy, you're a genius. I was wondering how it could be so unpredictable, but it actually wasn't. I was looking in the wrong direction. Thanks again!

Comment: glad I was able to help!